# Sqlite query to get the all child and sub-child by the parent id from two tables:

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables like eg.

Table1

```
id  title 
1   t1
2   t2
3   t3
4   t4
5   t5
6   t6
7   t7
```

Table2

```
id  tid  parent_id
1    2   1
2    3   1
3    4   2
4    5   3
5    7   6
```

I am getting the results only for one level by inner join with the parent id and the query is:

```
SELECT id,title
from table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table2.tid = table1.id
where table2.parent_id = 1
```

I just want the output all the child and sub-child of parent id like.
let's suppose here i just want the all child and sub-child for the parent id 1 then output will come eg:

Output

```
id title
2   t2
3   t3
4   t4
5   t5
```

Because t2,t3 parent id is 1 and t4,t5 is under the 2 and 2 is under the 1 parent id as well as t3 also.

so I want all the child and subchild by the parent id.

If you have any confusion please let me know thanks

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: could you please write a query to access?

Answer (score 0):

You want a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select t2.tid
      from table2 t2
      where t2.parent_id = 1
      union all
      select t2.tid
      from cte join
           table2 t2
           on t2.parent_id = cte.tid
     )
select t1.*
from cte join
     table1 t1
     on t1.id = cte.tid;
```

Comment: is it possible without the recursive function because when i am using this ionic sqlite that is showing error but when i am using this at local system that working fine. and simple query and join are working fine in ionic sqlite but i guess there is issue with the recursive function.

Comment: @shivchauhan . . . The keyword `recursive` may be needed.

Comment: I have used the recursive but still showing error! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Find all descendants of top-level items

```
with recursive hier(topid, tid, parent_id, level) as(
  select t1.id topid, t1.id tid, null parent_id, 1 level
  from Table1 t1
  where not exists(select 1 from Table2 where tid = t1.id)
  union all
  select h.topid, t2.tid, h.tid, level+1
  from hier h 
  join Table2 t2 on h.tid = t2.parent_id
  order by level desc
) 
select  h.topid parent, h.tid descendant, t.title, h.level
from hier h
join Table1 t on t.id = h.tid 
where level > 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a244312ce37564b55e5c09f28fa8c8e6)